# next-auth credentials provider server error

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am new to web development and I am adding authentication to my next.js project using next-auth and the credential provider, at first the api/auth/signin address took me to the base login form, but suddenly it started to give me the error:

error displayed

[image: 1]

when checking the server-side console

```js
[next-auth][error][INVALID_CALLBACK_URL_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#invalid_callback_url_error Invalid callback URL. Received: [object Object] 
InvalidCallbackUrl: Invalid callback URL. Received: [object Object]
    at assertConfig (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\assert.js:62:12)
    at NextAuthHandler (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:70:52)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async NextAuthNextHandler (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:23:19)
    at async C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:59:32      
    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:179:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:381:9)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:497:37)
    at async Router.execute (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:213:36)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\alfon\Documents\GitHub\Matrix_Family\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:616:29) {
  code: 'INVALID_CALLBACK_URL_ERROR'
}
```

my code on the api is

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"


export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: 'credencials',
            credentials: {
                username: { label: 'username', type: 'text', placeholder: 'username' },
                password: { label: 'password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'your password' },
            },
            authorize: (credentials) => {
                if (credentials.username === 'name' && credentials.password === 'pass') {
                    return {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'name',
                    }
                }

                //login fail
                return null;
            },
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
            // first time jwt callback is run,user object is available

            if (user) {
                token.id = user.id;
            }
            return token;
        },
        session: ({ token, session }) => {
            if (token) {
                session.id = token.id;
            }
            return session;
        }
    },
    secret: 'my secret in numbers',
})

//localhost:3000/api/auth/signin
```

I kept it simple but it still keeps on giving the error and I tried to start a new repository from 0 but without changes

my package.json is:

```js
{
  "name": "mantine-next-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "analyze": "ANALYZE=true next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "export": "next build && next export",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "jest": "jest",
    "jest:watch": "jest --watch",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "prettier:write": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "test": "npm run prettier:check && npm run lint && npm run typecheck && npm run jest",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7001",
    "storybook:build": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@mantine/carousel": "5.1.4",
    "@mantine/core": "5.1.4",
    "@mantine/dates": "5.1.4",
    "@mantine/form": "^5.2.3",
    "@mantine/hooks": "5.1.4",
    "@mantine/next": "5.1.4",
    "@mantine/notifications": "5.1.4",
    "@mantine/prism": "5.1.4",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.1.4",
    "@tabler/icons": "^1.78.1",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^7.0.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "next": "12.2.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.10.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "zod": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.1.4",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.12.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react": "18.0.16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-mantine": "2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.7",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "storybook-addon-turbo-build": "^1.1.0",
    "storybook-dark-mode": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

is from a mantine starter plate

I'm not really sure why it happened but I used this code instead and is working normally

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
      name: "Credentials",
      // The credentials is used to generate a suitable form on the sign in page.
      // You can specify whatever fields you are expecting to be submitted.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "correo"
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: 'clave'
        }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        if (credentials.email !== 'john@gmail.com' || credentials.password !== '1234') {
          return null;
        }
        // si todo esta bien
        return {
          id: '1234',
          name: 'john',
          email: 'john@gmail.com'
        };

      }
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  }
});
```

Comment: my node version is v16.14.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue and this solved for me perfectly.
First, open your browser console and navigate to **Application**
Then, delete or clear ur cookie (ex. http://localhost:3000/login) on the **Cookie** tab

**See picture below**

[image]

Answer (score -3):

`INVALID_CALLBACK_URL_ERROR` means that the `callbackUrl` provided was either invalid or not defined. See the [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl) doc for more information.

Comment: but i have seen that when you go to localhost:3000/api/auth/signin it should display a default signin page, when I was starting to test next auth it worked, but now it shows that error every time

Comment: This answer is what the actual issue is all about but does not provide any useful information on how to solve the problem.

It's pure copy paste from the next auth output, there isn't any solution provided.